# Mathematical definition of annihilation and creation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, definition, mathematics

I am self-studying quantum field theory and have gotten to creation and annihilation operators, respectively denoted $A^\dagger$ and $A$. Conceptually I understand what these objects are, at least on a surface level, which is they increase/decrease the number of particles present by one. In terms of maps:
$$A_n: H_s^{\otimes n} \rightarrow H_s^{\otimes (n-1)}\\ A_n^\dagger: H_s^{\otimes n} \rightarrow H_s^{\otimes (n+1)}
$$
where $H_s^{\otimes n}$ is the $n$-fold symmetric tensor product of a Hilbert space $H$.

The formula for these operators are:
$$A_n(\xi)(\beta)_{i_1,~\ldots,~ i_{n-1}} \equiv \sqrt{n}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \xi_i^* \beta_{i_1,~\ldots,~i_{n-1}, i} \quad \quad \xi \in H, \beta \in H_s^{\otimes n}\\
A_n^\dagger(\eta)(\alpha)_{i_1,~\ldots,~ i_{n+1}} \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n+1} \eta_{i_\ell} \alpha_{i_1,~\ldots,~\hat i_{\ell}, \ldots,~ i_{n+1}} \quad \eta \in H, \alpha \in H_s^{\otimes n}.$$

I have been having trouble breaking down the above formulas. Why is $\eta$ subscripted by $i_\ell$ and why is $\xi$ is just subscripted by $i$?

Also, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both $n$-tensors, so how are we taking $\alpha$ to be subscripted by $n+1$ indices in the creation operator, and what is the logic behind attaching an $i$ for $\beta$? Mathematically it seems after the summation the right hand side of both operators will still be $n$-tensors. I must be misunderstanding something with the indices here.

Comment: Which book/ source?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Talagrand's QFT book, it is written for mathematicians which I have a background in as opposed to physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $\eta$ is subscripted by $i_\ell$ because the indices $i_1,...,i_{n+1}$ are given on the left hand side and we are summing over *their sub indices*
- Talagrand gives on p. 79 the example
  $$\tag{A}
  A^\dagger_2(\eta)(\alpha)_{i_1i_2i_3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\eta_{i_1}\alpha_{i_2i_3}+
  \eta_{i_2}\alpha_{i_1i_3}+\eta_{i_3}\alpha_{i_1i_2})
  $$
  in which $\ell$ runs through $1,2,3$.
- To get out of that subindex business perhaps it is helpful to write (A) equivalently as
  $$\tag{A'}
  A^\dagger_2(\eta)(\alpha)_{\mu\nu\rho}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\eta_{\mu}\alpha_{\nu\rho}+
  \eta_{\nu}\alpha_{\mu\rho}+\eta_{\rho}\alpha_{\mu\nu})\,.
  $$
- $\alpha,\beta$ are both $n$-tensors. Note hovewer that the $\hat{i_\ell}$ is *omitted*. We subscript $\alpha$ always only with $n$ indices. See again (A) where $\alpha$ is a $2$-tensor.
- To $\beta$ we are not attaching an index $i$. We are contracting the $n$-tensor with a vector which results in an $(n-1)$-tensor -as it must because one particle gets destroyed.
- The $i$ is just a dummy index which for which one could use any symbol that was not used yet. It would be clumsy to use a subscript for $i$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So the subindices in $\eta$ is simply to agree with the summation? Because we see $i_1, \ldots, i_{n+1}$ in $\xi$ as well, but in that case we simply have $\xi_i$ (i.e. there is no subindex). Regarding his example on p. 79, on the left hand side he has $i_1, i_2, i_3$, and comparing to the definition of $A^\dagger$, this would imply that $n = 2$. Hence, $\alpha \in H^{\otimes 2}$, so how can we even speak of a third index $i_3$ for $\alpha$?

Comment: For $\beta$, what do you mean by contracting the $n$-tensor with a vector? I have not seen this terminology before.

Comment: Lots of questions in very short time. See edit of a way avoiding subindices. Where in $\xi$ do you see $i_1,\dots, i_{n+1}$ "as well". $\xi$ is a vector that carries a single index. when you sum over it as we do in the contraction it does not matter how you name that dummy index. Contraction is such a basic business in tensor calculus that I can expect you to google it or learn about it in other books. For example *Spacetime and  Geometry* by Sean Carroll.

Comment: Finally. To $\alpha$ in (A) and (A') we attach always only *two* indices. I said that before.

Comment: Thank you again, I think it's slowly starting to make sense. What is still unclear to me is, in the example, if $\alpha$ is a 2-tensor how are we speaking of an index $i_3$? Also, isn't the goal to make a 3-tensors out of these 2-tensors? But the RHS is a linear combination of 2-tensors so isn't it still a two tensor.

Comment: Rename $i_3$ to $\rho$ as I did in (A') and you'll be fine. Let's reconvene tomorrow. Things have to settle in a bit.

Comment: I will think about this in the meantime, thank you for all your help.

Comment: The RHS of (A) and (A') is a three tensor because it carries three free indices. All you have to keep track of are dummy indices (renamable as you like) and free indices which are externally given.

Comment: I have been thinking of this issue and things unfortunately are still unclear to me. However, after some thought I am beginning to think in the case of $\alpha$ even though we are referring to $n+1$ terms it is essentially a reshuffling of indices (as we still have $n$ terms this is okay). But I am not sure if this is correct. By the way, I also opened a question regarding this on math SE as I figured the question is more mathematical than physical.

Comment: It is correct. In the toy example (A) $\alpha$ is nothing else than a matrix and so carries two indices each of which can loop through at least $n+1$ values. In fact, in QFT these matrices allow loops through $\mathbb N$. I recommend again the Sean Carroll book. Embarking on a self-study of QFT is admirable but also means (with Seven Weinberg) to "go where the mess is".

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'm happy to hear that my understanding is correct. I plan on getting to general relativity eventually, but I hope to properly understand differential geometry before tackling that.

Comment: Be sure to understand DG from a rigorous mathematical standpoint. I am kidding. Those mathematical DG books can be awfully abstract. Sean Carroll's book or, say, the "phone book" *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler are marvellous pedagogical texts that teach you the necessary DG at the same time.

Comment: I actually am a student of mathematics, so I do not mind the abstractions, but I will surely check out those texts as well. Thank you again!

Comment: I spent some time reading up on tensor contractions, and they appear to reduce the overall dimension of the tensor by 2 (by summing over a given pair of upper and lower indices), however this is a little different than what I have in my post. Have I made a mistake?

Comment: I thought I had understood these expressions but I'm starting to realize that must have been an in illusion. Why is the creation operator summed over $\ell$ but annihilation operator is summed over $i$, when both have the LHS indexed by $i$?

Comment: Not sure from what sources you learn contraction. Simple case: a $2$-tensor carries two indices and a vector carries one. If we contract that tensor with that vector we effectively multiply a *matrix* with a *vector* and get a *vector* aka a $1$-tensor. Order reduction by one. Regarding your last comment: Both LHS are ***not*** indexed by that naked $i$. They are indexed by a bunch of indices which we may as well rename by greek letters as I have done in (A') in the answer above.

Comment: I tried going through the book by Sean Carrol you suggested as well as a few other sources online, most of which say you turn one covariant and one contravariant index into a dummy term and sum over them, making a $(m, n)$ tensor into one that is $(m-1, n-1)$. For the second question, I am confused on why one summation runs over $\ell$ and one over $i$, but I suppose this has to do with the construction (omitting $\hat{i}_k$ and contracting by $i$).

Comment: $V^\mu$ contravariant vector. $T_{\nu\rho}$ a $(2,0)$ tensor . Contraction $V^\nu T_{\nu\rho}$ a $(1,0)$ tensor. If you prefer to see this first as a $(2,1)$ tensor $V^\mu T_{\nu\rho}$ of which you trace out $2$ orders that's fine as well. I cannot believe those difficulties.

Comment: I do not think that is the issue for me, I think I just need more familiarity with tensors in general. But thank you again for all your help and patience.

Comment: No problem. I have bought Talagrand's new QFT book a few months ago and need motivation from a fellow reader to dive into it. I appreciate your patience as well !